# « Le même an » ou « la même année » ?

Tags: usage, locutions, indications-de-temps

Est-ce qu'on dit « le même an » ou  « la même année »  danc ce contexte :

> Elle s'est mariée en 2010 et le même an/la même année elle a trouvé un nouveau travail.

Comment: nGram Viewer de Google est un bon outil pour les questions d'usage : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+m%C3%AAme+an%2Cla+m%C3%AAme+ann%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20m%C3%AAme%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20m%C3%AAme%20ann%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

Vous n'entendrez jamais  « le même an » de nos jours ; c'est une locution qui a été utilisée il y a longtemps mais on ne s'en sert plus du tout.

On trouve la vieille forme encore en 1870, par exemple dans le livre suivant : «
[Recueil de travaux relatifs à la philologie et à l'archéologie](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QKYTAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA144&dq=%22le+m%C3%AAme+an%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjai4i9gPLmAhWB0eAKHV7tCxYQ6AEIhwEwDQ#v=onepage&q=%22le%20m%C3%AAme%20an%22&f=false) ».

- Cependant il ne me paraît pas douteux qu'ils n'appartiennent l'un et l'autre au même an du même règne et peut-être au même papyrus. Voici mes raisons: 1° Leur date commence par le même an et le même mois.

Il est utile de savoir, donc, que cela se disait dans le passé.

Answer (score 2):

> Elle s'est mariée en 2010 et la même année elle a trouvé un nouveau travail.